# How to set time auto redirect in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can anyone help me how to set time to auto redirect if my script is executing.

I want to have a timer because it will automatically redirect to the page and my confirmation popup dialog box close so fast.

current code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 // show a dialog box when clicking on a link
$.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Congratulations! </strong> <br> ' +
                         'You have successfully registered!', {
                         'type':     'confirmation',
                         'title':    'Non-uniformed Personnel (NUP)',
                         'auto_close': 10000
                        });
window.location.replace("index.php");

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.replace("index.php")
},5000);
```

This will set the location to replace in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try using setTimeout. Using setTimeout you can control the time duration after which you want to do any action.

Answer (score 1):

May be you want something like this :

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// show a dialog box when clicking on a link
$.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Congratulations! </strong> <br> ' +
                      'You have successfully registered!', {
                      'type':     'confirmation',
                      'title':    'Non-uniformed Personnel (NUP)',
                      'auto_close': 10000
                    });
setTimeout(function(){       
 window.location.replace("index.php");
 },10000);

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout` after the dialog

```
 $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Congratulations! </strong> <br> ' +
                         'You have successfully registered!', {
                         'type':     'confirmation',
                         'title':    'Non-uniformed Personnel (NUP)',
                         'auto_close': 10000
 });

setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.replace("index.php")
},10000);  //change the time value accordingly
```